# How to avoid specifying sub function arguments in main function?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I use Python to write scripts. I use main function to call other functions (subfunctions). So every time I add new subfunction I have to add new arguments into main function. **How to avoid that?**

For example I have 2 subfunctions and 1 main function:

```
def Func1(arg1, arg2): DoStuff1
def Func2(arg3, arg4): DoStuff2
def MainFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    return Func1(arg1, arg2) +  Func2(arg3, arg4)
```

I wrote a new function:

```
def NewFunc(arg5, arg6): DoStuff3
```

Then I must specify `arg5, arg6` into `MainFunc`:

```
def Func1(arg1, arg2): DoStuff1
def Func2(arg3, arg4): DoStuff2
def NewFunc(arg5, arg6): DoStuff3
def MainFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg5):
    return Func1(arg1, arg2) +  Func2(arg3, arg4) + NewFunc(arg5, arg6)
```

**How to avoid adding all those sub arguments into main function?**

Comment: Is there a specific pattern to this? Since this doesn't only affect the number of parameters in this function but also the number of arguments the caller has to pass, can't this be summarised as "how to pass lots of data around properly"? (The answer to which probably involves defining some data structures/classes.)

Comment: There are multiple solutions to this and the correct answer depends on your specific problem. Please show us your actual code so we can see which solution is applicable.

Comment: @deceze I am not real programmer (self-taught). I use sub functions to hide code complexity.

Comment: @rje My task is to write code for automate data downloading. Each of my sub functions do some part of the job (authentification, querry, response handling, download, etc.)

Comment: Then consider starting with passing a dict which describes the “request” (or whatever you’re expressing there exactly), instead of individual values: `MainFunc({'url': 'foo', ...})`.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine multiple arguments into one tuple param and use it like this

```
def Func1(arg1, arg2): DoStuff1
def Func2(arg3, arg4): DoStuff2
def MainFunc(*arg):
    return Func1(arg[0], arg[1]) +  Func2(arg[2], arg[3])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def func(arg1, arg2):
    pass

def func2(arg3, arg4):
    pass

def func3(arg5, arg6):
    pass

def main(*args):
    return func(*args[:2]) + func2(*args[2:4]) + func(*args[4:6])
```

Other way:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
    pass

def func2(arg3, arg4, **kwargs):
    pass

def func3(arg5, arg6, **kwargs):
    pass

def main(**kwargs):
    return func(**kwargs) + func2(**kwargs) + func(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use argument unpacking, and define your functions accepting an arbitrary number of positional arguments:

```
def func1(*args): # do stuff 1
def func2(*args): # do stuff 2
def new_func(*args): # do stuff 3
def main_func(*args):
    return func1(*args[:2]) +  func2(*args[2:4]) + new_func(*args[4:])
```

But, it won't be more **readable** and it won't be as **explicit** as what you have so far. Both of those do count!